# DOMReady: 'kendo' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, readystate

I am receiving an intermittent error from JavaScript in my production environment and was hoping to learn more about the loading process.

The error is simple enough to understand:

> 'kendo' is undefined.

It states that the `kendo` variable is undefined at a time that I try to use it. However, I have all of my JavaScript code wrapped inside a jQuery `ready` event, like so...

```
<head>
   <script src="path/to/jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- ... -->

   <script>
     jQuery(function ($) {
       var test = new kendo.data.DataSource({
         // datasource options
       });
     });
   </script>

   <!-- ... -->

   <script src="path/to/kendo.js"></script>
</body>
```

I was under the impression that doing `jQuery(function() { ... });` would cause the inner code to run after the DOM is ready and that it would run only after all of the `<script>` tags have been parsed and processed.

Is this not the case? Should I be adding my code to the `loaded` event instead of the `ready` event?

FWIW, we are using Cloudflare to handle minifying and caching, and the intermittent behavior seems to only be related to IE. I can't replicate the problem, though, I just get notified when one of our pages fails to finish loading and I see the console has this undefined error. Navigating to the page again yields no problem, so I'm a little baffled. Any ideas?

Also, I don't see any duplicate references to the jQuery or kendo libraries in my code.

Comment: I deleted my answer, the more you know, I guess, thanks.

Comment: @DmitryPonkin We're all here to learn something...appreciate your time and thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it this way ...

```
<head>
   <script src="path/to/jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- ... -->

   <script src="path/to/kendo.js"></script>
   <script>
     jQuery(function() {
       var test = new kendo.data.DataSource({
         // datasource options
       });
     });
   </script>

   <!-- ... -->

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my proposed solution to my employer (though I recommended putting kendo in the `head` as well). My concern is that I thought the whole point of the jQuery ready event handler was to ensure the entire DOM has been parsed. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I'm baffled as to why the current implementation would work most of the time if organization of resources was indeed the problem.